# Storing on the external storage card

Tags: java, android, storage, external, android-sdcard

I want to store data recorded with the accelerometer on the external storage but I have an error when I try to create the directory in which I want to save the data. My code is as follows :

```
dataDirectory=Environment.getDataDirectory();
path=DataDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
path+="/"+getResources().getString(R.string.DirectoryName);
myDirectory=new File(path);
myDirectory.createNewFile();
```

The `createNewFile` call triggers an `IOException`.

I can add two things : the `path` variable is set to "/data" after the call to `getAbsolutePath` and the `getExternalStorageState` function returns "mounted".

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have permission to write in the `/data` directory

- Use the sdcard directory
- Or try working in the `/data/data/com.yourapplication/files` directory where you do have permission. Use `Context.getFilesDir()` to get the path of your application's working directory.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
path=DataDirectory.getAbsolutePath().toString();
```

add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest file